# Lamps in parallel and series circuit - which will light up?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Will both lights in this circuit light up? It seems to me that the first light on the left is in series, and therefore will not light up.
Thanks for any explanation.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the switch is open, then both the bulbs will light up, since they are in series
[provided there is sufficient current through them]. If the switch is closed, then the bulb below the switch does not glow, since there is a zero resistance path through the switch [no current flows through that bulb]. In this case however, the other bulb will glow.

Comment: Thanks very much. I didn't know that about the zero resistance path.

Comment: I can't until 3 minutes!

Comment: Also, if these are different lights, you can have the situation (even with open switch) that only one of them lights up [because the current is not sufficient for the other light].